# Is the union of a countable collection of lines countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that if sets $A=\{m_1x+b_1, m_2x+b_2,...\}$ and $B=\{l_1x+c_1, l_2x+c_2,...\}$ are countable, so is $A \cup B$; however, can I extend this out to $A \cup B \cup C \cup D...$ (all the lines in $\mathbb{R^2}$?) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Considered as lines, as long as your union has only countably many items the whole collection is countable.  Each line corresponds to a pair of numbers, the slope and intercept, as you have shown.  The union of those sets is a countable set of ordered pairs.  As there are uncountably many lines in $\Bbb R^2$, your countable union cannot cover all of them.

Comment: I'm sort of getting it. What would be a counterexample of this? Or is it because I've defined those lines to be countable that I can make this argument and my counterexample would depend on the set that I've defined as countable?

Comment: Any countable union of countable sets is countable, at least in $ZFC$.  I don't know what you are looking for a counterexample of.